# How to let a uint8_t const* point at the same address as a char*?

Tags: c++, ns-3

In a C++-program I have a char* pointing to the beginning of an array containing BUFFER_SIZE number of chars (each char the size of one byte).
I now want to use that code in an NS3-simulation, which packets takes as input a uint8_t const* , pointing to a buffer.

What should I do in order to create a 'uint8_t const*' which points at the first mentioned buffer?

Answer (score 2):

You must either use `reinterpret_cast`:

```
int main () {
 char buffer[10];
 reinterpret_cast<unsigned char const *>(buffer);
}
```

or use a C-style cast:

```
int main () {
 char buffer[10];
 (unsigned char const *)buffer;
}
```

Comment: is  `const_cast` in this case necessary or is it compiler dependent ? http://codepad.org/nDZCA2zX

Comment: Neither. It isn't required at all. I must have confused myself while I tested it. I've updated my answer. Thanks!